# How can I recover overwritten file in mac?

Tags: bash, macos, iterm2

I accidentally did `echo 'export BUNDLER_EDITOR=code' > ~/.bash_profile` to add line to `.bash_profile` which overwritten previous scripts. How can I recover previous script? But I have iterm2 terminal open with previous `.bash_profile` setting, can we get content of `.bash_profile` from open terminal.

Comment: Nope, you have to go to your backup.  You do have a backup, don't you?  Your other session will have the same (overwritten) file unless you have it open in an editor.

Comment: i have sessions open from previous bash_profile but no backup, how can I restore it from opened session. I will do accept answer if you guide me in answer. Thank you.

Comment: @codemilan Again: Your other session will have the same (overwritten) file unless you have it open in an editor. This implies that you cannot restore it from that other session. There are chances that you can restore the one or other variable setting from that session (by outputting the variables), but any program calls or whatever are gone.

Comment: If you still have a Terminal open, you can run `declare -p > $HOME/NEWPROFILE` and recover your environment variables and function definitions. Also recover aliases with `alias > $HOME/ALIASES`.

Comment: yeah got it @Mark Setchell, Thank you. any how I managed to recover .bash_profile from .bash_profile.swap file

Comment: @codemilan: the was a good idea going for the swap file, but that was a backup file from a previous edit, so it will probably be out of date.  Still, better than nowt.   Take a backup now?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Do you mind making that an answer so that I can favourite it?

Comment: @ThomasKühn No problem! You can favourite and up-vote it ;-)

Comment: `.bashrc` isn't necessarily just alias definitions and variable definitions. There could be lots of arbitrary logic implemented that can't be recovered just by looking at the resulting state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still have a Terminal open, you can maybe salvage some aspects of your environment.

So, for your environment variables and function definitions:

```
declare -p > $HOME/NEWPROFILE
```

And for your aliases:

```
alias > $HOME/ALIASES
```

---

For more help on the `declare` command, use:

```
help declare
```

Comment: There you have the upvode :D